# RabbitMQ / AMQP design: How can I have some messages to be processed by one consumer, and but observed all consumers?

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I have an application that has 3 instances/replicas (three applications of the same kind are run simultaneously). They all consume the same queue, so RabbitMQ delivers messages in round robin fashion. All three instances share a single database that they r/w to.

This works great when the queue receives, let's say, `new-user` message, delivers it to one instance, and that instance saves the user to the common database.

The problem:
Given a message `new-user`, I want one instance to save it to the database (as before), but now I want all three to invalidate their caches. So I actually need all instances to receive the same event, but only one of them to act differently.

How can you design a system that allows these requirements?

The best way I can think of is to have two exchanges (`fanout` and `direct`), `new-user` message to be sent to a separate application which duplicates it and sends it to `fanout` and `direct` exchanges. All instances listen to both exchanges, and depending on the message handler, decides on what to do (if the message is from `fanout` exchange: invalidate the cache, if it's from `direct` exchange, well, only one would receive it anyways).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be a problem with your approach. If messages from `fanout` exchange will arrive `before` user was actually created, your instances may invalidate cache too early.
I think you should do the following:

- Have `direct` exchange and worker queue where all your user creators are getting messages in round robin, like you have it now.
- When instance created a user, it sends a message `user created` to a `topic` or `fanout` exchange, where all user creators are listening. Then all of the instances (including sender) will receive the `user created` event and will invalidate their cache.